# I tried opening my site in my browser i host on heroku, i got an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, mongodb-atlas, heroku-cli

[this the error message, i ran the this code heroku logs --tail in my terminal and i got this messages from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr4MD.png)

[message from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fMud.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt89o.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY6oH.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When i want to load my site that is hosted on heroku it shows that error i screenshot